# How to lock a scroll bar with another in a list in VB?

Tags: vb.net

I have a program that has two lists and the scrollbars to these lists need to be in the same vertical position.

Recipe++++++++++++++++++Servings
Spaghetti Bolognese +++++3

Pepperoni Pizza ++++++++4

However with enough recipes the two scrollbars appear for each the recipe list and servings and when you scroll on one list the other is out of sync showing the incorrect values next to each other.

Comment: Have you looked at using a multi column listbox instead?

Comment: Sorry I am unaware at what this is, could you please explain the_lotus

Comment: There's a [property on the listbox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.multicolumn(v=vs.110).aspx) to add more than one column to the listbox. Check out [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa975520(v=vs.71).aspx) for a small tutorial. Or search for "multi column listbox" on google image to see what it looks like.